# Converter is invoked and works, yet Hibernate throws SerializationException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity with an attribute that I want to serialize as JSON:

```
@Entity
public class Flujo implements Serializable {

  ...
  @Column(length = 5000)
  @Convert(converter = FASSignatureBlockArrayConverter.class)
  public FirmaAsyncSimpleSignatureBlock[] getBloquesFirmas() {
      return this.bloquesFirma;
  }

  public void setBloquesFirmas(FirmaAsyncSimpleSignatureBlock[] bloquesFirma) {

    this.bloquesFirma = bloquesFirma;
  }
}
```

the converter is implemented as follows

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class FASSignatureBlockArrayConverter
  implements AttributeConverter<FirmaAsyncSimpleSignatureBlock[], String> {

  private final static Logger LOG =
    Logger.getLogger(
        FASSignatureBlockArrayConverter.class.getName());

  public String convertToDatabaseColumn(FirmaAsyncSimpleSignatureBlock[] signatureBlocks) {
    LOG.info("Convirtiendo a JSON");
    if (signatureBlocks == null) {
        return null;
    }

    var mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(signatureBlocks);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException jpe) {
        LOG.log(
            Level.WARNING,
            "Converter, error convirtiendo to JSON",
            jpe);
        throw new RuntimeException("Error convirtiendo FirmaAsyncSimpleSignatureBlock[] a JSON", jpe);
    }
  }

  public FirmaAsyncSimpleSignatureBlock[] convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
    LOG.info("Convirtiendo desde JSON " + dbData);
    if ((dbData == null) || dbData.isBlank()) {
        return null;
    }

    var mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        var resultado =
            mapper.readValue(dbData, FirmaAsyncSimpleSignatureBlock[].class);
        LOG.info("Returning array of size " + resultado.length);
        return resultado;
    } catch (JsonParseException | JsonMappingException e) {
        LOG.log(
            Level.WARNING,
            "Converter, error convirtiendo desde JSON",
            e);
        throw new RuntimeException("Error JSON a FirmaAsyncSimpleSignatureBlock[]", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOG.log(
            Level.WARNING,
            "Converter, IO error convirtiendo desde JSON",
            e);
        throw new RuntimeException("Error IO convirtiendo de JSON a FirmaAsyncSimpleSignatureBlock[]", e);
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to persist a bean with an array of 0 length, it works ok.

When I try to persist a bean with an array of 1 length, having asinged an instance to the 0 position, I get

> 14:51:26,173 INFO  [es.ssib.otic.jpa.beans.converters.FASSignatureBlockArrayConverter] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 113) Convirtiendo a JSON
>   14:51:26,177 INFO  [es.ssib.otic.jpa.beans.converters.FASSignatureBlockArrayConverter] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 113) Convirtiendo desde JSON [{"minimumNumberOfSignaturesRequired":0,"signers":null}]
>   14:51:26,183 INFO  [es.ssib.otic.jpa.beans.converters.FASSignatureBlockArrayConverter] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 113) Returning an array of size 1
>   14:51:26,190 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 113) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."frontend.war".undertow-deployment:
>    org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."frontend.war".undertow-deployment: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>    org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not serialize
>           at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)
>           at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
>           at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>           at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
>           at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
>           at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
>   ...
>   Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.fundaciobit.apisib.apifirmaasyncsimple.v2.beans.FirmaAsyncSimpleSignatureBlock

How can I solve this? Obviously the converter is working as expected and it is not throwing any exception and it is returning the expected values.

I am using JPA on top of WildFly 18.0.0.1, which uses Hibernate's implementation.

---

Update 1: I have changed my property to be a *FirmaAsyncSimpleSignatureBlock* instead of a *FirmaAsyncSimpleSignatureBlock[]* (and I did adapt the converter) and it did work without any issues.

---

Update 2: Working on top of update 1, I built a "wrapper" bean that just held a *FirmaAsyncSimpleSignatureBlock[]* property and created the converter for it, and it works flawlessly; I do not know if it is a Hibernate bug with arrays or that I should specify that the attribute is an array in a different manner. And while this workaround works for me I am an sticker for clean code so I am still working for a proper answer.

Comment: Well, the exception is pretty self-explanatory. Does `FirmaAsyncSimpleSignatureBlock` implement `Serializable`? (it's not about *JSON* serializability or the conversions between JPA and RDBMS representations, it's about Java's serialization mechanism)

Comment: @crizzis No, it does not, but since my converter is taking care of the conversion to and from String I do not think it should matter. And additionally my last update shows that when I serialize a single instance and not an array Hibernate does not care at all.

Comment: I still fail to understand. You declared `Flujo` as `Serializable`. Yet, one of the properties of `Flujo` is not `Serializable`, hence the error. I don't see how an attribute converter (which is **not** involved in any way in **Java serialization mechanism**) is relevant to the question

Comment: It is not an issue with Java serialization, it is an issue with **JPA/Hibernate** serialization when persisting the entity.

Comment: 'It is not an issue with Java serialization' - `java.io.NotSerializableException` in the stacktrace contradicts that

Comment: Hibernate is trying to persist the entity without applying the converter on the custom type. If it conversion is done properly the data will be serializable and the issue does not occur. @SJuan76 Can you post your final approach in detail as answer?